# Realm doesn't find existing items

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm using Realm 3.4.0 and having one object that should be a singleton. The database is synced.

Here is a simplified version of the code: test if that object exist, add it if it doesn't exist. What is the correct way to do that? (copyToRealmOrUpdate shouldn't be needed or is there any other reason why the instance becomes null?)

```
@PrimaryKey
public long id = 1;

public static PlannerManager getInstance(Realm realm) {
    PlannerManager ourInstance = null;
    if (instanceLock == null)
        instanceLock = new ReentrantLock();
    try {
        instanceLock.lock();
        realm.refresh(); // Force getting all data from online database
        ourInstance = realm.where(PlannerManager.class).findFirst();

            if (ourInstance == null) { // The item doesn't exist
                realm.beginTransaction();
                ourInstance = realm.copyToRealm(new PlannerManager()); // Crashes sometimes with the error that an object with primary ID already exists
                realm.commitTransaction();
            }
        } finally {
          instanceLock.unlock();
        }
        return ourInstance;
    }
```

Relevant part of the stacktrace

```
2:9.446 Primary key value already exists: 1 .
(/Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsObject.cpp:189) io.realm.exceptions.RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Primary key value already exists: 1 .
(/Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsObject.cpp:189)
    at io.realm.internal.OsObject.nativeCreateNewObjectWithLongPrimaryKey(Native Method)
    at io.realm.internal.OsObject.createWithPrimaryKey(OsObject.java:198)
    at io.realm.Realm.createObjectInternal(Realm.java:1052)
    at io.realm.PlannerManagerRealmProxy.copy(PlannerManagerRealmProxy.java:1279)
    at io.realm.PlannerManagerRealmProxy.copyOrUpdate(PlannerManagerRealmProxy.java:1268)
    at io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator.copyOrUpdate(DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java:438)
    at io.realm.Realm.copyOrUpdate(Realm.java:1660)
    at io.realm.Realm.copyToRealm(Realm.java:1072)
    at com.myapp.internal.PlannerManager.getInstance(PlannerManager.java:857)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Stack trace for crash would be nice to have if exists.

Comment: Your primary key 'id' is always 1. You need to create a unique primary key for every instance.

Comment: @cykopath There should only be one single instance, that's why I have primary key 1 so it can't be doubled and search for any instance before inserting the only instance that should exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is actually slightly wrong. By doing the query outside the transaction, the background sync thread might put data into Realm between you do the query and begin the transaction. Transactions will always move the Realm to the latest version, so calling `refresh()` is also not needed. Your logic should be something like:

```
    realm.beginTransaction();
    ourInstance = realm.where(PlannerManager.class).findFirst();
    if (ourInstance == null) {
      ourInstance = realm.createObject(PlannerManager.class, 1);
      realm.commitTransaction();
    } else {
      realm.cancelTransaction();
    }
```

Note, that using `realm.copyToRealm()` will cause changes from other devices to be overridden, so for initial data like this, it is safer to use `createObject` as changes to individual fields will then merge correctly. Using `copyToRealm()` is the same as actually setting all fields to the initial value.

E.g if you have two devices A and B that are both offline:

1. A starts app and creates the default `PlannerManager`.
2. A modifies a field in `PlannerManager`.
3. B starts the app, but since A is offline, it doesn't know that PlannerManager is already created, so it also creates the default PlannerManager.
4. A and B both go online.
5. Due to how Realm uses "last-write-wins", B will now override all changes done by A, since using `copyToRealm` is the equivalent of setting all fields manually.

Using `Realm.createObject()` uses a special "default" instruction for all fields, that automatically loses to any explicit set like the one used when using normal Java setters (and which `copyToRealm` uses).

Comment: The problem is that I need to merge the data from each device that logs in to the account, and this only runs the first time the online database is created from the first device. So unique data from the other devices, from before connecting to the synced realm will then get lost.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! I will look into that! I've never understood the difference with the createObject so I never used it.

Comment: Could you say that every class that has a primary ID should use either createObject or copyToRealmOrUpdate and never copyToRealm?

Comment: Pretty much yes. `copyToRealm` will throw an error if an object with the ID already exists, so you should only use copyToRealm if you can guarantee the object doesn't already exist.

Comment: One last question: does realm.beginTransaction take some time to perform. For example if I did for (int I = 0; I < 100; ++i) PlannerManager.getInstance(realm).doSomething(); Then beginTransaction/cancelTransaction would happen a lot of times (and I do have a lot of that in the code, since I changed from a "normal" singleton pattern to using Realm)